# Add image in toolbar, but it must be bigger then toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, toolbar

I need image witch partly in toolbar and partly in view. I does not find good examples of it, maybe someone know how to do it? I currently work in Xamarin, but examples for Android Studio will be helpful to.

[image]

Comment: I believe the best way to do this is by making a translucent line on bottom of toolbar. I read a question few weeks ago about it I'll see if I can find it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380159/how-do-i-make-an-icon-seem-like-it-sticks-out-of-the-toolbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CoordinatorLayout` and a `layout_anchor`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_anchored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" android:src="@drawable/image_anchor"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar" app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|start|left"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a custom view for the ActionBar?

And also you can set custom height for the ActionBar.
Then I think your content can go behind the ActionBar. And you can use transparency on the ActionBar too.